# Why does adding one give you the number of factors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As many of you know, when we want to find out the number of positive factors a number has, we take the prime factorization and then we add one to the exponents and then we multiply the numbers. For example, if we want to find how many positive factors 280 has, we find that the prime factorization is:

$2^3 * 5^1 * 7^1$, so then we take $(3+1)(1+1)(1+1)$ and find that the number of factors is $4*2*2=16$. I tried to figure out where this comes from, but I can't find anything.

So my question is where does this come from?

Comment: Sorry if this question is too basic for this website.

Comment: @ultralegend5385 yes thank you very much.

Comment: when you accept an answer, please upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2^3 \cdot 5^1 \cdot 7^1$

for the factors of $2$ you can have 0, or 1 or 2 or 3 (i.e., 3+1)

for factors of 5 you can have 0 or 1 (i.e., 1 + 1)

for factors of 7 you can have 0 or 1 (i.e., 1 + 1)

Multiply them.